# Table created dynamically and DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset, sqldataadapter

In my windows form I have to create a table (at runtime) of specified by the user name (in textbox) and then use this table as datasource of `DataGridView`. Finally, the filled table must be inserted into the database. I tried to solve this problem in two ways:

1. I have created a DataTable, specified its columns etc. but I couldn't insert the DataTable into the database, even using `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` - propably I misused `DataAdapter`. I'm working with `C#` for 1 week and I don't fully understand the idea of `DataSet`s, `TableAdapter`s etc. So I decided to use SQL commands.
2. Using `ExecuteNonQuery()` I've created table in my database, then I recognized, that I have to use magic SqlDataAdapter and I gave up.

I want to manage the content of `DataGridView` in the same way, as in the case of `DataTable` added to `DataSet` using configuration wizard.

I know, that I can skip `DataGridView`, create list of textboxes, button expanding this list, and function inserting all fields into my table after confirmation button, but my supervisor expects `DataGridView`.

I can't paste the code here, because I left only copy of source code on company computer. If it will be necessary I will paste here my code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the method either `RowValidating` or `CellValidating` of `DataGridView`

```
  private void dataGridViewEnterTab1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridViewEnterTab1.IsCurrentRowDirty) // Trigger when the row is dirty or has changed
        {
            string userName = dataGridViewEnterTab1["UserNameCol", e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();

            //...Your SqlDataAdapter or codes
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help this idea. :)